# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Tags: java, struts

I want to populate a list of strings from a form.

My form bean:

```
public class TaskForm extends ActionForm{
    List<String> task = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<String> getTask() {
        return task;
    }
    public void setTask(List<String> task) {        
            this.task=task;         

    }
    }
```

My jsp:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
<textarea class="SubTaskTextArea_Style" id="task" name="task"></textarea></td>
}
```

strutsconfig:

```
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="TaskForm" type="controller.form.TaskForm" />

</form-beans>
<action-mappings>
    <action path="/TaskAction" type="task.action.TaskAction" name="TaskForm">
</action-mappings>
```

The situation is the `textarea` can be in any number, I want to get the string in textarea to be populated to the `formbean`.

But it gives the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: BeanUtils.populate
    org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:1099)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:798)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:254)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1422)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:523)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(PropertyUtils.java:1789)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.setNestedProperty(PropertyUtils.java:1684)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.setProperty(PropertyUtils.java:1713)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.setProperty(BeanUtils.java:924)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:729)
at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:1097)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:798)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:254)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1422)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:523)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the way you are trying to show the values is not correct.
Try something like this:

```
<s:iterator value="task">
       <textarea><s:property /></textarea>
</s:iterator>
```

Would like to know how you want to display the list items ?

EDIT:

Here it goes:

```
<%int i = 0; %>
<s:iterator value="task">
    <input type = "text" name = "t<%=i++%>" value="<s:property/>">
</s:iterator>
```

Whatever values would be entered in the text fields so created, will automatically be populated in the list **task**

Comment: thanks for the reply,Actually i have a list of text area in which the logined user has to enter their planned tasks, one for each text area,i want these task in TaskAction.java to  store it in database.pls help

Comment: For this, there can be two cases :  

1. If there are few(probably four or five) tasks, then you can have four or five different fields in your action class which are named-mapped from four-five text areas in jsp.


2. The above one should ideally not be the case, as in future there might be an increase in tasks so you would be creating more text areas and corresponding fields in action class. So for this : either you can have one text area and ask user to enter the tasks separated by comma and then parse them in your action class.

Comment: mine is the case two but there can be hundreds of textarea(requirement is like that), so here i want the text enter in every textarea to be loaded in a list(in form bean) but i could not get it done, how can i achieve the desired result in this scenario

Comment: This isn't the correct version of Struts; OP is using Struts 1.

Comment: oops... my bad. I missed it.

Comment: `<s:iterate name="task" id="taskId">
<input type = "text" name = "t<%=i++%>" value="">
</s:iterate>`

How about this one?

Comment: @Vaibhav Shukla now i am getting ths error javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean task in any scope,i could n't find the reason

Comment: In your struts Action execute method, before returning do this
**request.setAttribute("task", task);** . Task being the list name.